# Laplace equation with piece-wise constant boundary conditions, using change of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have a problem trying to find a solution of this problem:

> Find a harmonic function $u(x,y)$ in the region ${\operatorname{Im}(z)>0}$ with:
>   $$ u(x,0) = \begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{if } x\ge 0\\ 0 & \textrm{if } x<0 \\ \end{cases} $$

then I'd like to use that idea for solving this other problem:

> Find a harmonic function $u(x,y)$ in the region ${\operatorname{Im}(z)>0}$ with:
>   $$ u(x,0) = \begin{cases} T_1 & \textrm{if } x < a\\ T_2 & \textrm{if } a\le x\le b \\ T_2 & \textrm{if } x > b \end{cases} $$

I did this for the first problem:

I defined a $g(z)= z = x+iy$

then I said, for an $h$ in polar coordinates:

$h(g,0)=0$

$h(g,\pi)=1$

so $h(g,\theta)=A\theta+B$

where $A=\frac{1}{\pi}$ and $B=0$

then I said:

$$ u(x,y)=h(\operatorname{Re}(g),\operatorname{Im}(g))=\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) $$

but when I compute $u(x,0)$ it looks like this:

$$u(x,0)=\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(0)=0, \forall x$$

so it must not be a solution.

What should I do in this situation? What's wrong in the method that I proposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems. First, your boundary conditions are wrong.

$$u(x > 0,0) = h(r,0) = 1$$ 
$$u(x<0,0) = h(r,\pi) = 0$$

therefore $h(r,\theta) = 1- \dfrac{\theta}{\pi}$

Second, converting back to Cartesian isn't as straightforward as taking the arctangent, since the function $\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ only gives values between $(-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, and it isn't the case here. You have to split up the domain like this

$$ \theta = \begin{cases} \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right), & 0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2} \\ \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + \pi, & \frac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \pi \end{cases} $$

because when $x < 0$, $y > 0$, $\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ gives an angle in the range $(-\frac{\pi}{2},0]$, which is not what we want.

Finally, we have

$$ u(x,y) = -\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + \begin{cases} 1, & x> 0 \\ 0, & x < 0 \end{cases} $$

Alternatively, you can also write

$$ u(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) $$

by noting that $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} - \phi$ where $\frac{x}{y} = \cot\theta = \tan\phi$

Comment: Thank you! Shouldn't it be: $$ u(x,y) = -\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+ \begin{cases} 1, & x> 0 \\ 0, & x < 0 \end{cases} $$ ?